# iText set pdf permission witch signed certification

Tags: security, pdf, itext, document, restriction

Good day.
I need to sign a document with a certificate and configure security settings in PDF (Not Allowed).

Help me understand how you can change the value?

Thank

[image]

Рere is an example code:

```
...  
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0', new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")), true);
PdfSignatureAppearance sigApp = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("/resources/SDD.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font fnt = new Font(bf);
sigApp.setLayer2Font(fnt);
sigApp.setReason(reason);
sigApp.setLocation(location);
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
PrivateKey key = provider.getPrivateKey(in.getCertificate());
ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(key, in.getAlgorithm(), provider.getProvider());
MakeSignature.signDetached(sigApp, digest, signature, certs, null, null, tsc, 0, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CADES);
```

this code is not for me:

```
stamper.setEncryption("" .getBytes(), "" .getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.SIGNATURE_APPEND_ONLY, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
```

I find only such an option setEncryption(***). But this function creates a file (PDF). And when I sign with a certificate, a file (PDF) is also created, but without security parameters.

Comment: *"configure security settings in PDF (Not Allowed)"* - which settings shall be set to "Not Allowed"? *"this code is not for me"* - do you mean it does not work for you? In which does it fail?

Comment: I find only such an option setEncryption(***).
But this function creates a file (PDF). And when I sign with a certificate, a file (PDF) is also created, but without security parameters.
I need to change from allowed to not allowed: Commenting: Not Allowed, and Filing of form fields: Not Allowed

Answer (score 0):

If your signature is the first signature of the document in question, you can simply set the certification level as strict as possible:

```
PdfSignatureAppearance sigApp = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
sigApp.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
```

This should disallow any Commenting or Filing of form fields.

Comment: If I will sign the first signature of the document, security restriction will be applied.
If I will apply the second signature or any others certifications they will not be valid, Also  I wouldn't be able to check the first signature of the document.

            System.out.println(sigApp .getCertificationLevel()); //Everytime shows 0

Comment: *"If I will apply the second signature or any others certifications they will not be valid"* - you said you wanted to disallow filling form fields. Signing is filling a signature form field. Thus, you wanted further signatures to be disallowed. So if you somehow apply them nonetheless, they must be invalid.

Comment: I do not understand why it is not allowed to select only the properties:
**Commenting, Filling of form fields.**